# Angular Error when enbedding ng-switch inside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to nest **ng-switch-when** insides of **ng-repeat**?

```
<div ng-controller="UserController">
                            <div ng-switch on="renderPath">
                                <div ng-repeat="route in routes">
                                    <div ng-switch-when="route.path">
                                        <div ng-include src="route.url"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I got the following exception when I run it:

```
    Error: Argument '?' is required
pa@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:16 ...

<!-- ngSwitchWhen: route.path -->
```

Thank you!

**EDIT**

What I am trying to accomplish is the following

```
<div ng-switch on="renderPath">
                                    <div ng-switch-when="path1">
                                        <div ng-include src="url1"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div ng-switch-when="path2">
                                        <div ng-include src="url2"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div ng-switch-when="path3">
                                        <div ng-include src="url3"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

So I was wondering if I can use **ng-repeat** to help ne reduce the redundant HTML template code (**ng-switch-when**) above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't nest them.  ng-switch adds an entry to the $$watchers array on the ng-controller $scope.  ng-repeat creates a new child scope for each iteration.  When ng-switch-when is encountered, (I'm guessing here) it can't find any ng-switch information in the current $scope (which is now the ng-repeat child scope), so it fails.

**Update**: I looked into this some more.  The error happens with 1.0.3, but not 1.0.4 (but it doesn't work with 1.0.4 either).  What is actually going on is that the ng-switch-when scope is a child scope of the controller's scope, not the ng-repeat iteration child scope.  Therefore, `route` is not visible to the ng-switch-when directives.  Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqsrk/1/) that uses 1.0.4 -- you can click some links to see the controller, ng-repeat, and ng-switch-default scopes.  Examining the ng-switch-default scope, you can see that its $parent is the controller's scope, not an ng-repeat scope.

Comment: Mark, but I thought the scope is inherited. So it does not look up the scope chain? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think ng-switch on should be followed by ng-switch-when. In your case you are having a

`<div ng-repeat="route in routes">`in between.

The logic you have shown does not require ng-switch or maybe i am missing something.

Comment: thank you. I have edited the question. Hopefully it is a bit clear.